# Android scrolling

Tags: android

Everybody know how Rubik's cube works.
Is it possible to do somenthink like that in android:
I have 5 on 5 square buttons. Is it possible to rotate them as Rubik's cube (2D)?
If i have something like this:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

It's possible to scroll lines vertically or horizontally. But i want to scroll objects somtimes horizontally and somtimes vertically. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it wont work like that. Scroll in scroll doesn't work well on Android. In order to do something like that I'd suggest you make your own type(s) of `ScrollView` where you look at the direction of the scroll and based on that input scroll or don't scroll.